# Unique constraint is automatically created in database

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, constraints, unique

I have discovered in our Postgres Database there is a unique constraint on a table, which we haven´t created.

**Error message:**

```
SqlExceptionHelper - FEHLER: doppelter Schlüsselwert verletzt Unique-Constraint »uconstr_service_out_mapping«
  Detail: Schlüssel »(service_id, mapping_id)=(7, 262144)« existiert bereits.
```

My first thought was, that Hibernate has to generate this constraint automatically. But we disabled the Auto-Generation of the DDL with the following configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value=""/>
```

We are using Liquibase to create the table:

```
<changeSet author="foo" id="bar">
        <createTable tableName="service_in_mapping">
            <column name="masterdata_type" type="INT4">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="service_id" type="INT8">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="service_type" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="non_matching" type="VARCHAR(20)"/>
            <column name="mapping_id" type="INT8"/>
        </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

How can this unique constraint be constantly created? Any ideas?

**Used Dependency Versions:**

- Hibernate 5.2.8
- Postgres Jdbc 9.1-901.jdbc4

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using such an outdated JDBC driver?

Comment: It is because we still use old Postgres 9 Databases.

Comment: Are you creating a primary key constraint or unique index for that table later in your Liquibase changeLog?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will update the driver. But do you think, that the old driver is the cause of my problem?

Comment: No it wont (that's why I wrote "unrelated"). The unique constraint is almost certainly created somewhere else in your Liquibase changeLog.

Comment: Yes, we are creating unique constraints on the table in changelogs. But the above mentioned unique constraint is not created by us and not in the changelogs.

Comment: I am 99.9999% sure it **is** somewhere in the changeLog. Postgres does not create such a constraint on its own. Are there any `<createIndex>` changes for that table?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn´t a <createIndex> on that table.